# node.js - how to write an array to file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a sample array as follows

```
var arr = [ [ 1373628934214, 3 ],
  [ 1373628934218, 3 ],
  [ 1373628934220, 1 ],
  [ 1373628934230, 1 ],
  [ 1373628934234, 0 ],
  [ 1373628934237, -1 ],
  [ 1373628934242, 0 ],
  [ 1373628934246, -1 ],
  [ 1373628934251, 0 ],
  [ 1373628934266, 11 ] ]
```

I would like to write this array to a file such as I get a file as follows

```
1373628934214, 3 
1373628934218, 3
1373628934220, 1
......
......
```

Answer (score 139, accepted):

If it's a huuge array and it would take too much memory to serialize it to a string before writing, you can use streams:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream('array.txt');
file.on('error', function(err) { /* error handling */ });
arr.forEach(function(v) { file.write(v.join(', ') + '\n'); });
file.end();
```

Comment: Why not put `file.end();` after the loop instead of testing the index?

Comment: Thanks! My arrays are in the order of 1000+ so this method works perfectly

Comment: odd, this is giving me error: `TypeError: v.join is not a function`, to troubleshoot, i logged `typeof(v)` within the loop and it is a string, [coderade's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51362713) doesn't seem to produce error though.

Comment: @user1063287 Double check that you're passing a multi-dimensional array (as in the OP)

Answer (score 55):

Remember you can access good old ECMAScript APIs, in this case, `JSON.stringify()`.

For simple arrays like the one in your example:

```
require('fs').writeFile(

    './my.json',

    JSON.stringify(myArray),

    function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Crap happens');
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Not related to ArrayBuffers

Comment: if `myArray` is huge, `JSON.stringify(myArray)` will become a problem.

Comment: For better readability, you can use `JSON.stringify(myArray, null, 1)`

Comment: @ThịnhPhạm How huge is too huge?

Answer (score 31):

To do what you want, using the [fs.createWriteStream(path[, options])](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) function in a ES6 way:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('file.txt');
const pathName = writeStream.path;
 
let array = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7'];
  
// write each value of the array on the file breaking line
array.forEach(value => writeStream.write(`${value}\n`));

// the finish event is emitted when all data has been flushed from the stream
writeStream.on('finish', () => {
   console.log(`wrote all the array data to file ${pathName}`);
});

// handle the errors on the write process
writeStream.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(`There is an error writing the file ${pathName} => ${err}`)
});

// close the stream
writeStream.end();
```

Answer (score 19):

A simple solution is to use [writeFile](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) :

```
require("fs").writeFile(
     somepath,
     arr.map(function(v){ return v.join(', ') }).join('\n'),
     function (err) { console.log(err ? 'Error :'+err : 'ok') }
);
```

Comment: If you do, don't forget the callback with err: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback

Comment: Not sure what's amiss, but my system pukes on this code as written.  `TypeError: v.join is not a function`

Comment: Missing a `)` after `'ok'`

Comment: @3zzy thanks, fixed. Please note that you can edit answers on SO

Comment: syntax error need to add

arr.map(function(v){ return v.join(', ') >>}<here<< ).join('\n'),

Comment: @GurjinderSingh yes

Comment: @zipzit might be a bit late, but make sure items inside your array are arrays and not strings, otherwise, you can't use join() function on a string.

Answer (score 4):

```
async function x(){
var arr = [ [ 1373628934214, 3 ],
[ 1373628934218, 3 ],
[ 1373628934220, 1 ],
[ 1373628934230, 1 ],
[ 1373628934234, 0 ],
[ 1373628934237, -1 ],
[ 1373628934242, 0 ],
[ 1373628934246, -1 ],
[ 1373628934251, 0 ],
[ 1373628934266, 11 ] ];
await fs.writeFileSync('./PATH/TO/FILE.txt', arr.join('\n'));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We can simply write the array data to the filesystem but this will raise one error in which ',' will be appended to the end of the file. To handle this below code can be used:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream('hello.txt');
file.on('error', function(err) { Console.log(err) });
data.forEach(value => file.write(`${value}\r\n`));
file.end();
```

> \r\n

is used for the new Line.

> \n

won't help.
Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384340/how-to-append-to-new-line-in-node-js)

Comment: That depends on the OS where the script is being run. For Linux \n is a valid newline. For Windows you need \r\n

Answer (score 3):

Try with this

`await fs.writeFileSync('arreglo.txt', arreglo.join('\n '));`

This code works for me

don't forget to import fs

`import fs from 'fs';`

Comment: Works great. Although the extra space isn't needed for the `.join('\n ')`, it adds a space at the beginning of each line starting at line 2.

Comment: Yeah, i added this space to separate data but this doesn't work for me hahaha, just add a space, I'm glad it works for you

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs');

var arr = [
  [1373628934214, 3],
  [1373628934218, 3],
  [1373628934220, 1],
  [1373628934230, 1],
  [1373628934234, 0],
  [1373628934237, -1],
  [1373628934242, 0],
  [1373628934246, -1],
  [1373628934251, 0],
  [1373628934266, 11]
];

const content = arr.map(item => item.join(', ')).join('\n');

const fp = 'output.txt';

fs.writeFileSync(fp, content, 'utf-8');

console.log('Array has been written to', fp);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.