# How can I create a txt file that holds the contents of an array in JavaScript?

Tags: node.js, matlab, serialization, ar.drone

I have several arrays that contain data that I would like to export, each array to a txt file, in order to be analyzed using MATLAB.

Let's say my array is:

```
var xPosition = [];

// some algorithm that adds content to xPosition

// TODO: export array into a txt file let's call it x_n.txt
```

It would be great to store each element of an array per line.

Comment: What environment is your JS running in: server (or similar), browser, …?

Comment: I am using NodeJS. My project consists on getting data from the AR.Drone 2.0 and compute other data. I'm sorry, but I have almost no experience with JS. I would like that the txt generated file be placed in the same directory where I am running the script.

Comment: Why not just use JSON? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33381-jsonlab--a-toolbox-to-encode-decode-json-files-in-matlab-octave

Comment: @Dan's suggestion is good too: if you wind up needing more structured data to go from Node to Matlab, JSON is a good format. I've used JSONLab (Matlab) and it worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you found works, but here's how I'd have done it:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var xPosition = [1,2,3]; // Generate this
var fileName = './positions/x_n.txt';    
fs.writeFileSync(fileName, xPosition.join('\n'));
```

This uses node's [synchronous file writing](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_filename_data_options) capability, which is ideal for your purposes. You don't have to open or close file handles, etc. I'd use streams only if I had gigabytes of data to write out.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a guide for the solution to my question in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614123/node-js-how-to-write-an-array-to-file/). The following code is what I ended up using:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var xPosition = [];

// some algorithm that adds content to xPosition

var file = fs.createWriteStream('./positions/x_n.txt');

file.on('error', function(err) { /* error handling */ });
xPosition.forEach(function(v) { file.write(v + '\n'); });
file.end();
```