# How to write array into txt file and download on a button press in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have an array of emails like

```
array ['abc@gmail.com', 'xyz@gmail.com', ycz@gmail.com']
```

I want to insert this array into a txt file and then download this on a button press. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614123/node-js-how-to-write-an-array-to-file]

Download:

```
<a href="test_file.zip" download>Download File</a>
```

Comment: this should be a comment since it's only linking to other question