# Writing an array to a file in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have an array of 32 strings called "arr" and I'm trying to save it to a file (like a txt file). I'm doing this in javascript because I'm getting this array from an html page.

I've tried this solution :
[node.js - how to write an array to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614123/node-js-how-to-write-an-array-to-file)

So this code :

```
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream('array.txt');
file.on('error', function(err) { /* error handling */ });
arr.forEach(function(v) { file.write(v.join(', ') + '\n'); });
file.end();
```

results for me this error :

> Error: Module name "fs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use
> require([])

I saw a solution there : https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror and tried this one :

```
require(['foo'], function (foo) {
    //foo is now loaded.
});
```

but it still results 3 errors :

- "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404    (Not Found)"
- "Refused to execute http://[...]/scripts/fs.js as script    because "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" was given and its    Content-Type is not a script MIME type. defaultOnError —    require.js:5:1663"
- "Error: Script error for "fs""

I'm a beginner in Javascript and I don't really understand how to use require.js.
I tried to find a solution but I everything resulted to those errors.

Could you help me to write arrays in a text file ?
Thank you for your help !

Comment: All you need is something like this `await fs.promises.writeFile("file.txt", arr.join(","));`, but this runs only in a nodejs server, not in a browser.  Browser Javascript code can't generally write to your local file system for security reasons.

Comment: Welcome JuniJ :) 
In which environment are you running this script? You are speaking of a website, so are you running it in the browser ? Or is it in a node.js console/script?

Comment: The stackoverflow answer you mentioned above is for 2 dimensional array.If you have a simple array with 32 strings, you don't need to use `v.join`. Just simply `file.write(v + "\n");`