# write file with "\n" with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im working with a lot of datas which i turned into arrays , for simplicity lets assume i have array that looks like this

```
["dataone:dataone","datatwo:datatwo","datathree:datathree"]
```

im writting output to the file using `fs.writeFile`

but the output is always in the same  row e.g  `dataone:dataone","datatwo:datatwo","datathree:datathree`

i would like to output to be like with "\n" e.g

```
dataone:dataone
datatwo:datatwo
datathree:datathree
```

is it possible to make output in file look  like this? im writting in into .txt file

Comment: Please edit to include the code you have tried thus far.

Comment: Repeat question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384340/new-line-in-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the data with line breaks before writing to file

```
var os = require('os');
var brk = os.platform().substring(0,3).toLowerCasee() === 'win'
    ? '\r\n' : '\n';

var data = ["dataone:dataone","datatwo:datatwo","datathree:datathree"]
fs.writeFile(filename, data.join(brk), {encoding : 'utf8'},  function (e) {
   // etc  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join your array with `\n` before writing it to the file:

```
var arr = ["dataone:dataone","datatwo:datatwo","datathree:datathree"]
var arr2 = arr.join('\n');
```