# How to move to next line in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

Today I just started with firebase NodeJs authenciation trigger to send an welcome email when a user first time signUp. Here is an index.js file from official documents(modified)

```
const APP_NAME = 'Incredible India Tourism';


exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

  const email = user.email; // The email of the user.
  const displayName = user.displayName; // The display name of the user.


  return sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName);
});

exports.sendByeEmail = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {
// [END onDeleteTrigger]
  const email = user.email;
  const displayName = user.displayName;

  return sendGoodbyeEmail(email, displayName);
});
// [END sendByeEmail]

// Sends a welcome email to the given user.
function sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName) {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: `${APP_NAME} <noreply@firebase.com>`,
    to: email,
  };

  // The user subscribed to the newsletter.
  mailOptions.subject = `Welcome to ${APP_NAME}!`;
  mailOptions.text = `Hey ${displayName || ''}! Welcome to ${APP_NAME}. We hope you will enjoy our service.`;
  return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
    return console.log('New welcome email sent to:', email);
  });
}

// Sends a goodbye email to the given user.
function sendGoodbyeEmail(email, displayName) {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: `${APP_NAME} <noreply@firebase.com>`,
    to: email,
  };

  // The user unsubscribed to the newsletter.
  mailOptions.subject = `Bye!`;
  mailOptions.text = `Hey ${displayName || ''}!, We confirm that we have deleted your ${APP_NAME} account.`;
  return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
    return console.log('Account deletion confirmation email sent to:', email);
  });
}
```

But how I can move to next line in this line

```
 mailOptions.text = `Hey ${displayName || ''}! Welcome to ${APP_NAME}. We hope you will enjoy our service.`;
```

I want to move to next line after

```
Welcome to ${APP_NAME}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New Line in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384340/new-line-in-node-js)

Comment: Ya I tried this but not able to implement here . I am new on nodejs

Comment: what happened when you wrote \n or \r\n... what was the result?

Comment: Nothing is happening but start making error actually the link you refer is quite different . In my case all are string so I don't know where I should use + "\r\n"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could you try this and share the output...

```
 mailOptions.text = `Hey ${displayName || ''}! Welcome to ${APP_NAME}. \n We hope you will enjoy our service.`;
```

you'd have to insert an **html option** if you want to include a link to an image... the previous code (above) sent text-only emails

```
mailOptions.html = `
Hey ${displayName || ''}! Welcome to ${APP_NAME}.  
<br />
<img src="cid:logo">
<br/>
We hope you will enjoy our service. <br/> `;
```

and

```
mailOptions.attachments = [{
            filename: 'angular.png',
            path: 'https://www.akberiqbal.com/logos/angular.png',
            cid: 'logo'
}]
```

Comment: Thanks first one is actually break the line but second one is not working can you please also tell me how I can show a image using  URL here

Comment: you need to insert an image (as a link) in the email?

Comment: No but show image in email using some URL  e.g const url ="image-link" show this in mailOption,text

Comment: Sorry @Akber Iqbal I just check your code but it is not showing an image , simply it is putting text as before

Comment: you just inserted the mailOptions.html part... not the mailOptions.text part, right?... because mailOptions.html will send an email where you can have an image... mailOptions.text just sends out a text email

Comment: So I need to add both mailOptions.text as well as mailOptions.html?

Comment: what text do you get... ?

Comment: Hey USER! Welcome to APP (Next Line)  We hope you will enjoy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186457/discussion-between-akber-iqbal-and-manik).