# Add newline at end of JS file using NodeJS and FS

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, newline, eof

I'm writing a NodeJS app using JS and `fs` to manage the filesystem.  I'm using `compile` and `resolve-to-string` to replace template strings with config values.  The result of that ends up in `content`.  I'm on a Mac.  Not sure that matters.

Then I have this:

```
  try {
    fs.writeFileSync(destFileName, content, 'utf8')
    fs.appendFileSync(destFileName, '\r', 'utf8')
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
```

`content` is a string and is written out to the `.json` file just fine.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to add a newline to the end of the file.  I've tried as many combos of `\r` and `\n` as I can think of.  I've tried a few different `fs` file options.  I've tried with and without `utf8`.  I assume it's something super small and silly but I can't see it.  :(

Following [aRvi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5460261/arvi) comment, I tried adding several `\n`'s to `content` and then `console.log`ing it.  All the extra newlines show up just fine in the console.  Then I tried writing `content` to a `.txt` file.  Extra newlines show up fine there too.  Then I tried renaming `.txt` to a `.json` file and the newlines disappeared.  Must be something to do with file format/extension.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384340/how-to-append-to-new-line-in-node-js

Comment: My initial Google search landed me there first.  I've tried several combinations of `\r` and `\n` without any luck.

Comment: `fs.writeFileSync(destFileName, content + "\n", 'utf8')` check if that works for you

Comment: Tried that too.  Also doesn't work.  I've added more details to the question RE to this.

Comment: When I replaced "\r" with "\n" in your code, it worked fine on my mac. How do you know the newline disappears in the .json file? How are you opening/viewing the .json file? There's a chance your text editor is modifying the file when you open/save it.

Comment: Have you tried viewing your modified file in different editors? Do they all behave the same?

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me. You'll need two newline characters if you're looking to actually have a blank line at at the bottom. One to end the current line, and the second to create the empty line below.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const { EOL } = require("os");

const destFileName = "./new-file.json";
const content = "hello world";

try {
  fs.writeFileSync(destFileName, content, "utf8");
  fs.appendFileSync(destFileName, EOL, "utf8");
  fs.appendFileSync(destFileName, EOL, "utf8");
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

```bash
$ cat new-file.js
hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
 fs.writeFileSync(destFileName, content + '\n', 'utf8')
```

It could be that your IDE/editor automatically removes any extra whitespace after the last character in the JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

Ran node code in node v16.15.1

Below I wrote some code that anyone can run to see that the console will log that three newLine characters in a row were there after the file was written to. This is most likely an IDE issue for most people because the default JSON formatter on Auto Save will remove any extra whitespace and new lines. I took the liberty of adding the .vscode/settings.json config to override this default functionality for your workspace.

```
const fs = require("fs");
    const content = `{
      "demokey": {
        "demokey2": "demovalue2",
        "demokey2": "demovalue2"
      }
    }
    `;
    try {
      fs.writeFileSync("./demo.json", content, "utf8");
      fs.appendFileSync("./demo.json", "\n\n\n", "utf8");
      const text = fs.readFileSync("./demo.json");
      const hasThreeLinesInARow = /\n\n\n/.test(text.toString());
      console.log(hasThreeLinesInARow);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
```

vs code config - save to project/.vscode/settings.json

```
{
    "json.format.enable": false,
    "json.validate.enable": false
}
```