# Adding args under last text added in .txt, discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made this command that should add args to a txt file, and it works well, there's only one thing left i wanna do, when it adds a new text to the txt it adds it right after the last text, is it possible to make it add the text under it instead?
This is what happens when i try to add something new, i want, in this case, the test 2 to be added under test:
[image]

```
const data = args.slice(0).join(" ");
        
    fs.appendFile('test.txt', data + " ", (err) => {  
        console.log('File edited')
        message.channel.send('test.txt updated')

    data.split('\n')
```

this is the code i made, hope you can help

Comment: I guess you should be adding line breaks such as `\n` or `\r` . Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/10384372/2312637.

Comment: i tried ('test.txt', data + "\r\n" and it works, thanks!